# Trying to prevent a modal opening on an escape key press in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a custom made modal that is randomly popping up on any page when the esc key is pressed. This is in React and I am having a hard time figuring it out. Any help would be great. I just need to figure out how to stop escape from opening it. Thanks!

```
import { h } from 'preact';
import { useEffect } from 'preact/hooks';
import FocusLock from 'react-focus-lock';
import { useEscapeHatch, enableScroll, disableScroll } from './helpers';

type ModalProps = {
  isOpen: boolean;
} & h.JSX.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>

const Modal = ({ isOpen, children, ...props }: ModalProps) => {
    const component = <div {...props} class={`modal ${isOpen ? 'open' : ''}`} role="dialog" aria-modal="true">{children}</div>;

    useEffect(() => {
      if (isOpen) {
        disableScroll();
      } else {
        enableScroll();
      }
    }, [isOpen]);

    if (isOpen) {
      return (
        <FocusLock returnFocus>
          {component}
        </FocusLock>
      )
    }
    return component;
};

Modal.Window = ({
    children,
    ...props
  }: h.JSX.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    return (
      <div
      {...props}
      class={`modal__window ${props.class ?? ''}`}>
        {children}
      </div>
    );
}

type ModalMaskProps = {
    onClose: () => void;
} & h.JSX.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>;

Modal.Mask = ({
    onClose,
    ...props
  }: ModalMaskProps) => {
    useEscapeHatch(onClose);
    return (
      <div {...props} onClick={onClose} class={`modal__mask ${props.class ?? ''}`} />
    );
}

type CloseIconProps = {
    onClose: () => void;
} & h.JSX.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>;

Modal.CloseIcon = ({
    onClose,
    ...props
  }: CloseIconProps) => {
    return (
      <button {...props} type="button" class={`ml-auto ${props.class ?? ''}`} onClick={onClose} aria-label="Close">
        <svg
          class="fill-current text-grey-700 w-6 h-6 cursor-pointer"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          viewBox="0 0 18 18"
        >
          <path d="M14.53 4.53l-1.06-1.06L9 7.94 4.53 3.47 3.47 4.53 7.94 9l-4.47 4.47 1.06 1.06L9 10.06l4.47 4.47 1.06-1.06L10.06 9z" />
        </svg>
      </button>
    );
};

export default Modal;
```

Here is the modal component and it works fine except it is opening up on escape (this is the holistic component and then I have sub-modals that use this. Thanks!

EDIT

```
import { useEffect } from "preact/hooks";
import { isInBrowser } from "../../constants/defaults";

/**
 * Use Escape(Key) Hatch
 * @param onCloseCallback method to be called when Escape key is pressed.
 * @returns void
 */
export const useEscapeHatch = (onCloseCallback: () => void) => {
    return useEffect(() => {
      const close = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (e.key === 'Escape') {
          onCloseCallback();
        }
      };
      document.addEventListener('keydown', close);
      return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', close);
    }, []);
};
  
export const disableScroll = () => {
  if (isInBrowser) {
    document.body.style.overflowY = "hidden";
  }
}

export const enableScroll = () => {
  if (isInBrowser) {
    document.body.style.overflowY = "auto";
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code? Seeing the Modal component would make it easier for us to know what the problem is.

Comment: Just posted some, thanks!

Comment: It seems like the problem could be with the useEscapeHatch method. Could you include the code in helpers.js?

Comment: @Justiniscoding I appreciate it